# ListView last entry repeat on back click

Tags: android, android-listview, baseadapter

Why Listview repeats last entry on back click??????First time when that class launched with ListView, all the data It is showing is correct, now I click on one of the list Item and again press back from description, then It repeats the last entry.

e.g.

ListItems are:
A -> B -> C

Now I click on B and go to the next page and from that I click on back, then the list is:

A -> B -> C -> C

and again when I press A and from that A description page, when I click back, then the list is:

A -> B -> C -> C -> C

why it is repeating the last entry????

The activity class code is as follow:

```
         if(list.isEmpty())
                            {
                                if(adapter==null)
                                {
                                        adapter=new MyAdapter(context, list);
                                        ls.setAdapter(adapter);
                                }
                                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                            }

     @Override
protected void onStop() {
    super.onStop();
   AppointmentListView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
}

@Override
protected void onRestart() {
    super.onRestart();
    AppointmentListView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
}
```

and MyAdapter class is:

```
public class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

        public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list;  
        Context context; 
        private LayoutInflater mInflater;
        String appointType;


        public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list)
        {  
            super();  
              this.context=context;
            this.list = list;  
            mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);

        } 

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.size(); 
        }
        @Override
        public int getViewTypeCount()
        {
            return 1;

        }



        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return list.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }

        static class ViewHolder {  
            TextView AppTime_List;  
            TextView CustomerName_List;  
            TextView CustomerAddress_List;  
            TextView AppID_List;
            Button MapButton;
            }


    //  @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            ViewHolder holder;  

            if (convertView == null)  
            {  
                holder = new ViewHolder();  
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.listviewsample, parent, false);  

            holder.AppTime_List = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.time);
            holder.CustomerName_List = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.name);
            holder.CustomerAddress_List = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.Address);
               convertView.setTag(holder);

            }  
            else  
            {  
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();

            }  

            appointType=(String)list.get(position).get("Name");

            holder.AppID_List.setText((String)list.get(position).get("ID"));
            holder.AppTime_List.setText((String)list.get(position).get("Time"));
            holder.CustomerName_List.setText((String)list.get(position).get("Name"));
            holder.CustomerAddress_List.setText((String)list.get(position).get("Address"));



            return convertView;  

        }


    }
```

Can anybody pls help me on that??

Comment: can you provide the activity code as well........

Comment: Can you provide part of your code where you are filling your list with elements?

Comment: Its on the top, pls check my question: activity code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here the problem is with MyAdapter getCount method. now in my MyAdapter class, I have declare list_size at the top:

```
 int list_size;

  public MyAdapter(Context context, ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> list)
{  
    super();  
      this.context=context;
    this.list = list;  
    mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
    list_size=list.size();

} 

  @Override
public int getCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return list_size();
}
```